# How to retrieve the 'Status' for 'ContributeID = 149' without using 'ID'?

Tags: sharepoint-fields

```
ID    ContributeID   Status

3         150         Pass
2         149         Fail
1         148         Pass
```

Above is the data in a SharePoint List.

How to retrieve the 'Status' for 'ContributeID = 149' without using 'ID'?

Comment: Will the values in ContributeID column will be unique?

Comment: Yes...values in ContributeID will be unique

Comment: What type of coding method do you prefer? Server side code, CSOM, or JSOM?

Comment: @AsadRefai as I am a newbie to Sharepoint...i hardly know the difference.  However I would prefer using Sharepoint classes like SPList, SPListItem along with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the specific value of a specific field, using a CAML Query is much more direct than looping through all list items.  You would end up with code along the lines of:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(absoluteSiteUrl))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPList list = web.Lists["List Name"];

    string queryString = "<Where><Eq>";
    queryString += "<FieldRef Name='ContributeID' />";
    queryString += "<Value Type='Number'>149</Value>"; // you could put any value you are looking for here
    queryString += "</Eq></Where>";

    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = queryString;

    // getting items using a query will always return a collection object
    SPListItemCollection resultItems = list.GetItems(query);

    if (resultItems.Count > 0)
    {
        // if ContributeID is truly unique, there should be only one item in the collection
        SPListItem singleItem = resultItems[0];
        string status = singleItem["Status"].ToString();
    }
}
```

See also:

[How to retrieve list items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx)

[SPList.GetItems(query) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Get the site collection, then the web, then the list. Then, loop through each item in the list, checking `ContributeID` against the value you're looking for. There's a sample here: [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521580%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Look for the section starting with, "If you do not know either the GUID or the ID of the list item..."